# Store dates and rates in a Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, database-design

What is the best practice for this situation?

I am building a reservation system, and I'm looking at the best way to capture and store information from a user. Each resource is available for one day and can take any amount of users up to the maximum. So for example, say it's a hot air balloon with a maximum of 5 people. I want my form to look like this:

```
[Buttons to select # of guests]  // So if a user wants the same price for 1-3 people he only has to enter it once.

From [START DATE] to [END DATE]: [RATE]  // Where the []'s are input fields for the user
```

I plan to store each price in the database as:

```
Date, # of guests, rate
```

So one row for each date.

So I need to convert "`[START DATE]` to `[END DATE]`" to storing the values for each date.  Should I do that client side in Javascript, or in my controller in rails?  If the rates are the same for a set of guests, i.e. 1-3 guests, is there a way I can store that in the DB for better querying? Or should I not bother because if tomorrow the user wants to change the price for 2 guests, it might screw up my db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Start date` and `End date` vs. `Each date` - several conditions:

1. If the user wants to book a hot air balloon for 3 days, is it the same hot air balloon every day or can it change? If it can be different, have a `resources.type` field mapped to several `booked_resources.id`.
2. You need to check for overlaps of resource usage if you use separate `start` and `end` dates. Storing repeated records one-per-date with the `booked_resource.id` would remove the need for overlap checks. See this thread for a related question: [Storing Calendar Data in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368030/storing-calendar-data-in-mysql)
3. Sending the client-side JS an array of dates for each day can be more easy than extracting `for each day between start date and end date`. Pick whichever conforms best to your current code. Remember that either way, the SQL/date checking has to be modified to spot for unavailability.
4. If a user can change the number of guests and that affects cost, then **storing each individual date is more convenient for db updates of that kind** (like the itemized billng by Hotels). Otherwise you would need to 'split' records for the dates which have different # of guests.